# How to extend $.post() with more options from $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post, extend

Is it possible to extend the properties and options of jQuery's `$.post()` helper function.

I sometimes need to add more properties to `$.post()`, like `async, beforeSend, contentType, context, crossDomain, error, global, headers, ifModified, mimeType, timeout, etc` but I aviod to use `$.ajax()`, because I am too used to use `$.post()`, because of my habit.

---

**EDIT:** Is it possible to overwrite/override the whole helper plugin/function?

Comment: Change your habit? When `$.post` is not good enough, use what *is*.

Comment: $.post is just calling $.ajax for you though.

Comment: @Jon, that is hard and not good for future business. I just need to set my own custom properties which I will use time to time.

Comment: @Dreamwalker yes it does, but it has a limited number of properties and attributes: `url, sentData, completeFunction, dataType`, but I need more than that :)

Comment: @Zlatan: I don't agree with either of those statements. But even if I did, correct is correct. Also, it doesn't make sense to say that "X is hard" in this situation; you should find an alternative Y and compare the difficulty of X to that of Y. Which in this case will result in X not looking too hard after all.

Comment: Use $.ajax(). $.post() is just a wrapper for $.ajax() anyway.

Comment: well I work alone on my projects so I will be using that extened $.post(), and it will not have global change influence :)

Comment: @dotty, of course it is man, I know that.. But can we extend it, and/or overwrite and override it?

Comment: @Zlatan. sure you can, since jQuery is open source, go and find the part for $.post() then edit to your hearts content. This is extremely pointless though, you could just use $.ajax()...

Comment: @dotty, what if I'm using the minified jQuery? this is not pointless to me, as it is maybe to you :)

Comment: Well download the source from https://github.com/jquery/jquery, edit what you need to edit, do loads to testing to make sure it works, then minify it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function add your own arguments, it will update get method as well.  But as you can plainly see it is just wrapping $.ajax

(Taken directly from the jQuery source)

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
        // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        return jQuery.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: callback,
            dataType: type
        });
    };
});
```

EDIT - Example modified code all arguments are required

```
jQuery.each( [ "myPost" ], function( i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type, errorCallback ) {
        return jQuery.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: callback,
            dataType: type,
            error: errorCallback
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: as I said friend, I know it is wrapping $.ajax(), and I have no problem with that! and I think this is what I want! let me test first!

Comment: I wasn't sure what specifically you needed to add.  I would suggest using a different method name maybe for your modified versions.  So you can still benefit from the correct jquery post method

Comment: added an example of putting an error callback on and renaming the method to myPost.  it dosn't really need to be in a .each was been lazy :)